# Bitlocker on Windows 8.1 without TPM

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker, tpm

I just upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro because I want an additional layer of security in case my laptop (and research) gets stolen.
Didn't knew about the TPM, and seems I don't have it (I have an ASUS N550JV). So for what I read I need an USB pen drive plugged into the computer EVERY time it starts up.
I can deal with that.
Question is: after the computer starts, can I safely remove the USB drive, or does it need to be all the time there, consuming an USB port?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further reading I undertand that the USB drive is just for recovery purposes. No need to be attached during startup.

Comment: Ok i have to wait 10 hours